# APP + Framework7 + Vuejs

Tags: template-engine, vue.js, html-framework-7

Someone knows how to change the double brackets "{{" from Vuejs templating to another code? I am working on a app made with Framework7 and it's templating uses the same double brackets and I can't escape it to use on Vuejs!

Someone have any ideia or have a better solution?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but F7 now support Vue officially: https://framework7.io/vue/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Vue [delimiters](http://vuejs.org/api/#delimiters) to change the default `{{}}`

```
Vue.config.delimiters = ['@{', '}']
```

So now your double curly braces are ignored by Vue.